# fail to display phpmyadmin

Tags: php, windows-7, phpmyadmin

I configured apache, mysql and phpmyadmin as the following link described,

[configuration of apache, mysql and phpmyadmin](http://www.bicubica.com/apache-php-mysql/index.php)

I got all the correct result except the one last step, when I finished configuring phpmyadmin, I try to open http://localhost/phpmyadmin
But I can only get the index of the phpmyadmin folder. The webbrowser only list all the files in it without showing the log in box.

Can anyone help me a bit? thank you!

Comment: what if you go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php  ?

Comment: How on earth is this question *off-topic*? Stop being too quick to click on close.

Comment: This is off-topic, this is clearly not a programming issue but a server/configuration issue. I suggest migrating this to serverfault aswell.

Comment: Check the phpmyadmin folder for the index.php file because directory listing is usually as a result of missing index file.

Comment: Sorry, I will ask this kind of question in serverfault from now on.